# SugarCRM over ride the edit view buttons in custom view that extends ViewEdit?

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I have created a custom view in Calls that is based on the editview but I want to change the save button to post back to a custom action in my custom controller. I think I basically need to overide the editview defs with my own defs. I have tried adding calllistviewdefs.php but this doesn’t seem to work.

What is the correct way to override edit view buttons in this case?

Here is the code so far:

Controller

```
require_once('include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php');

class CallsController extends SugarController {

    function action_CallList() {
            $this->view = "calllist";
    }
}
```

view

```
 require_once('include/MVC/View/SugarView.php');

 class CallsViewcallList extends ViewEdit {

    public function CallsViewcallList() {
            parent::SugarView();

    }

    public function preDisplay()
    {

        parent::preDisplay();
        $metadataFile = 'custom/modules/Calls/metadata/calllistviewdefs.php';

    }

    public function display() {
        parent::display();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways, but I would suggest outputting javascript after parent::display() and hijack the existing Save buttons (top and bottom). Reset the onclick for those buttons to whatever you would like.

Comment: That’s what I ended up doing, surly there must be a correct way to do something like this though.